# Helm Set Docker Image Tag Dynamically

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am pushing Docker images to our private registry via Jenkins with the following command:

```
def dockerImage = docker.build("repo/myapp:${env.BUILD_NUMBER}")
```

(`BUILD_NUMBER` increases after every build.)

Because I am new to using Helm, I could not decide how should I give the tag for images in `values.yaml`.

I would like to deploy my app to multiple environments such as:

- `dev`
- `test`
- `prod`

Let's say I was able to deploy my app via Helm to `dev`, and the latest `BUILD_NUMBER` is:

- 100 for `dev`
- 101 for `test`
- 102 for `prod`

What should be the tag value, then?

```
 image:
  repository: registryt/myrepo/image
  tag:
```

Answer (score 8):

You should put "some" tag into your `values.yaml` which will act as the default `tag`. Each Helm Chart has it, you can check the official Helm Charts [here](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable).

Now, you have two options on how to act with the different environments.

## Option 1: Command line parameters

While installing your Helm Chart, you can specify the tag name dynamically with `--set`. For example:

```
$ helm install --set image.tag=12345 <your-chart-name>
```

## Option 2: Separate values.yaml files

You can store separate `values.yaml` in your repository, like:

```
values.dev.yaml
values.prod.yaml
```

Then, update the correct values in your Jenkins pipeline.

Comment: sorry I could not get the point, I can write tag:some , am I correct?

Comment: Yes, explore [these](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable) charts values.yaml files so you can understand better.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this issue with GitHub Actions. As the other answer already noted, set the image.tag in values.yaml to something as a default. I use *latest* as the default.

The problem is that the **`helm upgrade` command only upgrades if the image tag is different**. So "latest" isn't unique enough for Helm to do the rolling update. I use a SHA in GitHub Actions as my unique version tag. You could tag the image like this:

`def dockerImage = docker.build("repo/myapp:${env.NAME}-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}")`

Then in your helm command just add a --set:

`helm upgrade <helm-app> <helm-chart> --set image.tag=${env.NAME}-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}`

This command will override whatever value is in values.yaml. Keep in mind that the --set value must follow the structure of your values.yaml so in this case image is a top level object, with a property named tag:

```
values.yaml
     image
          name
          tag
          pullPolicy
     port
     replicaCount
```

Comment: How did you run the helm command in GitHub actions?  I'm trying to do this for a pod in AWS Elastic Kubernetes Service.

Answer (score -1):

May be its late, but hope helps someone later with this similar query.
I had similar situation and was looking for some options. It was painful as helm3 package doesn't come with --set option, which exists in version 2.

Solution:
Implemented with Python jinja packages, along with environment variables, with below steps.

**Create values.yaml.j2** file inside your chart directory, with your values file along with templates as per below.

```
name: {{ APPLICATION | default("SampleApp") }}
labelname: {{ APPLICATION | default("SampleApp") }}
image:
  imageRepo: "SampleApp"
  imageTag: {{ APPLICATION_IMAGE_TAG | default("1.0.27") }}
```

**Dependency packages (in container):**

```
sh 'yum -y install python3'
sh 'yum -y install python3-pip'
sh 'yum -y install python-setuptools'
sh 'python3 -m pip install jinja-cli'
```

**Sample Environment Variables In your Build Pipeline:**

```
APPLICATION= "AppName"
APPLICATION_VERSION= '1.0'
APPLICATION_CHART_VERSION= '1.0'
APPLICATION_IMAGE_TAG= "1.0.${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
```

Now in your pipeline, before packaging chart, Apply/Replace the templates with one jinja command as like below.

```
sh "jinja CHART_DIR/values.yaml.j2 -X APP.* -o CHART_DIR/values.yaml"
helm package CHART_DIR
```

Done!

Comment: Why not use Helm's native templating here?  Helm 3 still supports the `--set` option everywhere it was supported in Helm 2.